# image view with table view in the same view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a new controller defined as follows:

`@interface view1: UITableViewController`

I've created (in viewDidLoad) an image view (logo image) and added this image view as subview for view1, but the problem is that table view cells still appear behind this image view, how can completely separate the image view from the table view ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: all solutions are right, thank you hypercrypt, El Developer, DanZimm and Yogev Shelly very. But need an answer now: what is the best answer !!!?

Comment: If you want it floating on at all times, i.e. a section header, like the letters in address book then DanZimm's answer is what you want. If you want it at the top, like an extra row that scrolls up with the table view then mine is the best. The answers that manually add a subview to the view hierarchy are good if you don't want your view at the top (or bottom), they are a bit of a pain to get right and could break in future iOS releases if Apple changes their implementations. Thus if you want such custom behaviour then Yogev Shelly's option 1 is probably best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have a logo type view you either need to set a custom headerview for the tableview via

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

and

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

the other method would be overriding `-loadView` and creating your own view that has two subviews, your imageview and a tableview.

In the first method, once your scroll some the logo will eventually disappear. The second method makes the logo static.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding it in:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

This method is only called once you have called viewDidLoad so if you want something over everything else you might call this one or add the subview to:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:yourView];
```

Hopefully it helps you.

Comment: i believe he means that he wants the tableview to not be scrolling underneath of the image, not that the image isn't actually the top most view. He says that the imageview is on "top" of the cells but the cells are able to scroll underneath the imageview

Comment: If you do this in `-viewDidAppear:` then you need to be careful that you only call it once as `-viewDidAppear:` can be called multiple times if the view controller is presented and dismissed.

Answer (score 1):

2 options:

1.create a UIViewController to hold your UITableViewController controller view and your imageView, then position their frame so they wont overlap

2.add the imageView as a TableView Section Header

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
                              [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image" ofType:@"png"]]];
    return imageView;
}
```

and make sure you have at least 1 section of course in:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `-numberOfSectionsInTableView:` is optional. An implementation that returns `1` is redundant as a table view will have one section by default. It may be good to implement it anyway for completeness, but you do not need it.

Answer (score 1):

What is seems like you want is for your logo to be at the top, above your table view? If so then you can, in `-viewDidLoad`, set the `tableView`'s `tableHeaderView` to the view you want, e.g.:

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"]]; // assuming ARC, else autorelease or put in variable first...
```

If you want it to float on top when scrolling then DanZimm's use of `-tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` is what you want.